# Raspberry Pi 3 DHT 22 incorrect readings

Tags: pi-3, python, dht22, adafruit

I have configured the RPi to read value from the DHT 22 sensor. I have used AdafruitDHT library but when I start AdafruitDHT.py script I got totally incorrect value e.g. "Temp=537.7* Humidity=1152.0%"

I have to say that I made a mistake in the first wiring (I connect the data pin to 3v3 Volt of the raspberry and power supply pin to GPIO of the raspberry).

Did I fried the sensor making incorrect wiring?

Thanks

R.

Answer (score 1):

If you get any readings at all it is probably wired properly.

I suggest you try my [DHT Python script](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_code/DHT.py).

Leave the module with the name DHT.py and then issue the following commands in the same directory.

`sudo pigpiod`

`python DHT.py x`

Where `x` is the (Broadcom) number of the GPIO connected to the DHT22 data line.

https://pinout.xyz/